# show error if none of the checkboxes are selected

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, antd

I have a bunch of checkbox, and need to show a warning message if none of them are selected.
[image: checkbox screenshot]

Like this,
[image: WARINING message]

The only rule is that, if none of the checkbox is selected it must show the warning message like above when submitting, and no warning if anyone of them is selected.

my code:

```
             <Form.Item
                    name="checkboxes"
                    valuePropName="checked"
                    rules={[
                      {
                        required: true,
                        message: "Please select atleast one working day",
                      },
                    ]}
                  >
                    <Checkbox onChange={this.sun}>Sun</Checkbox>
                    <Checkbox onChange={this.mon}>Mon</Checkbox>
                    <Checkbox onChange={this.tue}>Tue</Checkbox>
                    <Checkbox onChange={this.wed}>Wed</Checkbox>
                    <Checkbox onChange={this.thu}>Thu</Checkbox>
                    <Checkbox onChange={this.fri}>Fri</Checkbox>
                    <Checkbox onChange={this.sat}>Sat</Checkbox>
            </Form.Item>
```

In the above code, it shows the warning even if one of any checkbox is clicked.

So, I tired changing the rules to,

```
            rules={[
              {
                required:
                  this.state.mon &&
                  this.state.tue &&
                  this.state.wed &&
                  this.state.thu &&
                  this.state.fri &&
                  this.state.sat &&
                  this.state.sun === false,
                message: "Please select atleast one working day",
              },
```

but in above case, it not even showing any warning message if none of the checkbox is selected.

I use *antd* for UI, and checkbox is import from it. (for ref: https://ant.design/components/checkbox/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This conditional, are you sure in it? `false` applied to `sun` only.

```js
this.state.mon &&
this.state.tue &&
this.state.wed &&
this.state.thu &&
this.state.fri &&
this.state.sat &&
this.state.sun === false
```

Your code: "if 6 days are selected and Sunday is false - then show error message"

I guess you need something like

```js
 {
   required: ![this.state.mon, this.state.tue, this.state.wed, this.state.thu, this.state.fri, this.state.sat, this.state.sun].some(d => !!d)
 }
```

Comment: Yes, Exactly. This statement was checking if sun is false only

Comment: Adding ! infront of each statement solved the issue :)